# How to use Angular js Validation with Google Api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, autocomplete

I am new in angularjs and trying to implement angular validation on  google API example `

> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

when i enter address it automatically fill state,city and county but angularjs still giving me error that city,state and country is required but these data have been automatically filled by google api

Angular Validation code is

```
<div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="email" class="control-label">*City:</label>
            <span class="help-block" ng-show="form.city.$invalid && form.city.$touched">
                <strong>*City is Required</strong>
            </span>
            <input class="form-control" ng-model="formdata.city" ng-required="true" name="city" value="<% formdata.city %>" id="locality" >

        </div>
```

But when i write city,state and country itself then everything is working fine. So how can i use it with google api

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any error with how you coded it as compared with this [sample](http://embed.plnkr.co/u91e8N/). You may want to check this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33355407/5832311). It suggested to isolate the validation and display of messages, accessing form etc from the `googlePlaces` directive. Here's also an [example from GitHub](https://github.com/vskosp/vsGoogleAutocomplete) - Angularjs autocomplete module using [Google Maps JavaScript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) and embedded autocomplete validator.

Hope this helps!